# SQL Server - cannot select rows with Sum > 0

Tags: sql-server, sum

I'm using SQL Server.
I have table with Hours values for different Tasks and days from 1 to 7, like so (table TaskHours):

```
        | TaskID | Hours1 | Hours2 | Hours3 | Hours4 | Hours5 | Hours6 | Hours7 |
        | 1      | NULL   | 10     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
        | 2      | NULL   | NULL   | 0      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
        | 3      | 0      | NULL   | 0      | NULL   | 0      | 0      | NULL   |
        | 4      | 3      | 3      | 0      | 3      | NULL   | NULL   | 3      |
        | 5      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
```

I need just calculate the sum of hours for each TaskID and select only those of them that has the Sum of hours > 0.
But when I try to write:

```
    SELECT TaskID, Hours1, Hours2, Hours3, Hours4, Hours5, Hours6, Hours7,
       SUM(ISNULL(Hours1, 0) + ISNULL(Hours2, 0) + ISNULL(Hours3, 0) + ISNULL(Hours4, 0)
        + ISNULL(Hours5, 0) + ISNULL(Hours6, 0) + ISNULL(Hours7, 0)) AS TotalHours
    FROM TaskHours
    WHERE TotalHours > 0
```

I then get the error:

```
Invalid column name 'TotalHours'.
```

What do I do wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: This is a consequence of SQL Server's [logical processing order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/).  TL/DR: Aliases from the select clause are only available to the order by.  Cross apply and subqueries can work around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this in subquery as below

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT TaskID, Hours1, Hours2, Hours3, Hours4, Hours5, Hours6, Hours7,
    ISNULL(Hours1, 0) + ISNULL(Hours2, 0) + ISNULL(Hours3, 0) + ISNULL(Hours4, 0)
    + ISNULL(Hours5, 0) + ISNULL(Hours6, 0) + ISNULL(Hours7, 0) AS TotalHours
    FROM TaskHours   ) a
WHERE a.TotalHours > 0
```

Comment: For this simple example, the subquery is probably fine. But it's worth noting that, for databases, it's often worthwhile from a performance standpoint to bite the bullet and copy/paste the complicated select expression into a where or group by clause. And then go take a shower afterwards because you feel so dirty for repeating code like that.

Comment: The difficulty comes from the fact that the schema is not normalized. Having the hours in a child table (1 : n) with only one `hours` column would allow us to write a simple `SELECT SUM(hours)` with `GROUP BY TaskID`.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, the problem is that `TotalHours` still doesn't exists when you write the `WHERE` clause.

So here is my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT TaskID, Hours1, Hours2, Hours3, Hours4, Hours5, Hours6, Hours7,
       (IFNULL(Hours1, 0) + IFNULL(Hours2, 0) + IFNULL(Hours3, 0) + IFNULL(Hours4, 0) + IFNULL(Hours5, 0) + IFNULL(Hours6, 0) + IFNULL(Hours7, 0))
       AS TotalHours FROM taskhours) as res WHERE res.TotalHours > 0;
```

Let me explain. This are called **SubQueries**. Which are queries inside queries. 
If you read the code that I just posted you'll notice the following structure.

```
SELECT * FROM (subquery) as fooName WHERE fooName.foo = 'something';
```

This structures forces 'subquery' to be completely resolved before the outer structure is called. So in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM(subquery) as res WHERE res.TotalHours > 0;
```

Now `TotalHours` exists since 'subquery' that has

```
(IFNULL(Hours1, 0) + IFNULL(Hours2, 0) + IFNULL(Hours3, 0) + IFNULL(Hours4,0) + IFNULL(Hours5, 0) + IFNULL(Hours6, 0) + IFNULL(Hours7, 0)) AS TotalHours
```

has been resolved.

Another thing. I removed the `SUM()` because you said:

> "since I need just calculate the sum of hours for each TaskID and select only those of them that has the Sum of hours > 0."

`SUM()` will actually sum all the outcomes of all the rows of your output leaving you with the total hours of all the TaskIDs in a single row like so:

[With SUM()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCf3p.png)

And to my understanding you need something like this:
[Without SUM()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcDvJ.png)

Finally: `IFNULL()` is the equivalent of `ISNULL()` in MYSQL.